# How to import Component in React

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to React and as I'm following a tutorial I need to divide different components into their own files. I tried making a separate file for the Header component but all I get is a white screen.

**Main React file**:

```
import Header from "./Header"

function Page(){
    return(
        <div>
           <Header />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The file for the Header component is called Header.js and it's in the same directory.

**Header.js**:

```
export default function Header(){
    return(
        <header>
        <nav className="nav">
            <img className="logo" src="./react-logo.png" />

            <ul className="nav-items">
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
    )
}
```

This is probably so simple to fix but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Anything in your console?

Comment: You component is fine, you should check the import part `import Header from "./Header"`. If it's under the different folder, you should consider something like `../components/Header`

Comment: Are you using webpack? create-react-app? esbuild?

Comment: give `../` to checkout and find path according to your folder depth

Comment: No, just plain HTML, CSS and JS with the react and babel cdn

Comment: i get this error in the console: index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:15
    at i (babel.min.js:24:29679)
    at r (babel.min.js:24:30188)
    at e.src.n.<computed>.l.content (babel.min.js:24:30503)
    at n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24:29946)

Comment: can you show us what error you got in console

Comment: uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:15
    at i (babel.min.js:24:29679)
    at r (babel.min.js:24:30188)
    at e.src.n.<computed>.l.content (babel.min.js:24:30503)
    at n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24:29946)
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
i @ babel.min.js:24
r @ babel.min.js:24
e.src.n.<computed>.l.content @ babel.min.js:24
n.onreadystatechange @ babel.min.js:24
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
s @ babel.min.js:24
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1

Comment: can you check this once might this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151731/trouble-when-trying-to-import-component-in-react